# Android 10 service stops working once not charging and screen turned off

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I wrote service to watch ping devices connected to my wifi in order to turn off heating in apartment on/off.

I was about to buy raspberry pi, but I got idea to use my old android 10 phone running lineage os.

I did write the service. It runs fine, until I turn the screen off. Then it stops pinging the devices and controling the heating api.

Once I turn the screen back on, it starts by itself again.

This is how I start the service:

```
        public void StartService()
        {
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(AutomationService));

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                context.StartForegroundService(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                context.StartService(intent);
            }
        }
```

Notification:

```
        public Notification GetNotification()
        {
            // Building intent
            var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            intent.PutExtra("Title", "Message");

            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var notifBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, foregroundChannelId)
                .SetContentTitle("Netatmo automation")
                .SetContentText("Running")
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            // Building channel if API verion is 26 or above
            if (global::Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(foregroundChannelId, "Title", NotificationImportance.High);
                notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
                notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
                notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
                notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
                notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

                var notifManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                if (notifManager != null)
                {
                    notifBuilder.SetChannelId(foregroundChannelId);
                    notifManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                }
            }

            return notifBuilder.Build();
        }
```

And the service itself:

```
    [Service]
    public class AutomationService : Service
    {
        public AutomationService()
        {
            controlApplication = new ControlApplication();
        }
        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public const int ServiceRunningNotifID = 9000;
        private readonly ControlApplication controlApplication;

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            Notification notif = DependencyService.Get<INotificationHelper>().GetNotification();
            StartForeground(ServiceRunningNotifID, notif);

            controlApplication.StartApplication();

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        public override bool StopService(Intent name)
        {
            return base.StopService(name);
        }

    }
```

This part `controlApplication.StartApplication();` is just starting while(true) loop in task doing the ping checks and sending http requests by logic.

Can someone help me how to keep the service alive when the screen turns off?

I opted to the phone first, since it will be more power efficient than the raspberry.

I will be glad for any input.

Cheers

EDIT--

This is StartApplication method... It doesn´t run on main thread.

```
        public void StartApplication()
        {
            this.Log().Debug("Starting application");
            _ = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(username, password).ConfigureAwait(false);
                pingWatchService.Start();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Might be easier to have a timer that starts a short-lived service periodically.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Mhm, gotta lookup some resources for that

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve any example or direction where to look? I am not sure how you mean it

Comment: I’ve never done it myself, but google `android timertask service` I see links like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21457046/199364.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the while(true) loop is run in the main thread. When the screen is off, the loop will block. So you service will be killed by the system. I have repeated your problem when I add a while(true) into the OnStartCommand method. And you can solve it just create a new thread to do the loop. Such as:

```
Thread thread = new Thread( controlApplication.StartApplication);
thread.Start();
```

Use the PowerManager Service:

Add the code to your service.

```
 private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
 PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)this.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
 wakeLock = powerManager.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial,Class.Name);
 wakeLock.Acquire();
```

And add the wakeLock.Release(); to the OnDestory method of the service.

Comment: Hey, I did add the StartApplication method to the main post. It doesn´t run on UI thread. I will test your suggestion nonetheless and report back

Comment: I can repeat your problem jusk like above. If the problem isn't the loop and just because the Android power policy. You can try to use the power manaer to make the cpu keep on. In addition, the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock) may help you.

Comment: @TomášFilip Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Not really, I did test out JobInfo approach, but that gets killed by doze. I did do a test run with AlarmManager, but that for some reason did not survive working through night - the alarm stopped popping

Comment: So the issue still is how to keep the loop in your foreground service run all the time.  Have you tried to run the loop in the service directly?@TomášFilip